# ASP.NET - SPGridView Paging is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a SPGridView, with AllowPaging = true and PageSize=3, but the paging row is not visible!!! 
When I move to design mode I can see the paging row, but on the web it's not visible.
I have tried to add  gridview.PagerTemplate = null before the DataBind() but it's still doesn't work. I also tried to add this gridview.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true but it's not working because BottomPagerRow is null. I really don't know what can help it.

Does anyone have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

do you have more than 3 records in your Datasource, Ideally it should show

```
 <asp:GridView ID="SPGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3"></asp:GridView>
```